# Merging dataframes, why do I get key error 'Bizot'?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, keyerror

I have 2 dataframes (their heads on the picture), and I can't merge them together. I have found the 'left join' merging, but when I try it, it gives back keyerror 'Bizot'. Why can it be?

```
esemeny_df = x_df.sort_index(axis = 0, ascending = False)
esemeny_df = esemeny_df.rename(index = str, columns = {'sum': 'Bizot'})

igeny_df = igeny_df.set_index(['Bizot', 'Kell'])
tigeny_df = igeny_df.T 

df = esemeny_df.merge(tigeny_df, how = 'left', left_on = 'Bizot' , right_on = 'Bizot')
print df
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also put some snippet of your data?

Comment: I guess you need `df = esemeny_df.merge(tigeny_df, how = 'left', on = 'Bizot' )` and remove `igeny_df = igeny_df.set_index(['Bizot', 'Kell'])` first.